# JsonView in Spring Boot not filtering response

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I'm working on a Spring Boot application and I'd like to filter some of my endpoint responses based on JsonView. I'm following the pattern laid out in

https://spring.io/blog/2014/12/02/latest-jackson-integration-improvements-in-spring

However the response always contains the full properties of my response object rather than the subset I would expect.

My (simplified) code:

```
@RestController
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class Controller {
    @RequestMapping("/")
    @JsonView(Responder.OnlyMyName.class)
    Responder home() throws JsonProcessingException {
        Responder responder = new Responder();
        return responder
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Controller.class, args);
    }
}
```

Responder

```
public class Responder {

    @JsonView(OnlyMyName.class)
    public String name="My name";

    @JsonView(Everything.class)
    public String value="My value";

    public class OnlyMyName{}
    public class Everything extends OnlyMyName{}
}
```

The response looks like this: `{"name":"My name","value":"My value"}` when I would expect it to be `{"name":"My name"}`.

Clearly I'm missing something, but I can't figure out what it might be.  Please help!

Comment: You might need `@ResponseBody` annotation

Comment: `@ResponseBody` annotation is implicit when you use `@RestController `

Answer (score 2):

the Jackson parameter MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION should be set on false.

Something like this

```
final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.configure(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION, false);
```

Comment: how to configure this in Spring boot 2 ?